# Ionic - How to remove android vertical scroller

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Hello I created an sample ionic tab app and as I do run android it shows on a vertical scroller on all pages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih7Ue.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ion-content` set attribute: `scrollbar-y` to `false` or `""`

see DOCS [ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/)

> scrollbar-y
>   (optional)
>   boolean 
>   Whether to show the vertical scrollbar. Default true.

Comment: Thanks for answering but can I know where can I put that because im using side menu should I do it like this <ion-side-menu-content scrollbar-y="">

Comment: Each view has `ion-view` that contains wrapper `ion-content`

Answer (score 1):

For Ionic 2, please add this to the .scss file.

```
.scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

To override in the whole app, add it to the app.scss file.

Comment: How about for Ionic 4?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Solution for hide ionic vertical scrollbar